# Confused by earlier errors - Bailing out

Tags: iphone

I am getting an unusual error when I try building or running my iphone game.

//GameScene.mm

```
- (void) onExit  
{  
    if(!([SimpleBox2dScrollerAppDelegate get].paused))  //error comes here
    {  
        [SimpleBox2dScrollerAppDelegate get].paused = YES;  
        [super onExit];  
    }   
}
```

//  SimpleBox2dScrollerAppDelegate.mm

```
+(SimpleBox2dScrollerAppDelegate *) get {  

    return (SimpleBox2dScrollerAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
}
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: What "unusual error" might that be?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta I believe it is the title of the post: "Confused by earlier errors - Bailing out". Have you tried cleaning the project and re-compiling? Do you get any other errors?

Comment: That implies that there were (likely relevant) earlier errors.

Comment: is there any other errors in your code except this one??

Comment: Nathan S. is definitely right.

Comment: Agree with Ishu.. Its nothing...just delete app from simulator..Clean all targets...Delete build folder..and run application

Comment: No Inder.No errors except this one.

Comment: @Mehul:Did this. Did'nt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing , probably you get a number of errors after that you did changes and get this kind of error.

follow thes steps it may be solve your problem.

-Delete the app from simulator.
-clean the all target.
-empty cache.
-delete build

Now try to run.